# Immediate function in script not being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script being loaded on my index.html page. It has dependencies on jQuery, bootstrap.js, & metisMenu.js all of which are being loaded before it. I can't figure out why this script is not being immediately executed.

If I open the chrome console and run the code, it works just fine, I'm also not seeing any errors in console.

**index.html**

```
...
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/custom/sb-admin.js"></script> //This is the script I'm referring to
</body>
```

**sb-admin.js**

```
$(function() {
    $('#side-menu').metisMenu();
});
```

What am I missing here? I'm almost positive `$(function() {...});` is shorthand for document ready in jquery, yes?

Comment: put `debugger;` as the first line of your function body and see if interpreter breaks there.

Comment: @zerkms - Good call, just did that and it's being executed. Looks like the page isn't actually finished loading...maybe due to angular loading the view. I'm going to try and change where the script is loading and see if that helps.

Comment: You know, that was it. I put the script in the nav (which is a separate view) and now it seems to be working just fine. Angular hadn't technically loaded that view yet even though JS thought document.ready had happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script is for the nav.html view, and on index.html, because I was using `<div ng-include="'views/nav.html'"></div>` the page had technically loaded and executed my script, even though Angular still was loading the `ng-include` view.

I moved the script into nav.html and now it seems to be working just fine. Thanks to @zerkms for reminding me to use `debugger;` which I should have done in the first place O_o

Comment: if you use angular, you need that inside controller or yourapp.run function, I believe.

Answer (score -2):

try instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

;-)

and if you try to do an **IIFE** (look on google)
do

```
(function() {

})();
```